# How can I assign a boolean to a double variable?

Tags: java, boolean, assign

If tax area is empty then, on board sales, on board services and pre-orders are tax free. I am trying to write this pragmatically in java. I declared on board sales, on board services, pre-orders as three fields which are of `double` datatype. How can I assign a `boolean` value to those parameters as tax free or not.

I want to use the `applyTax` `boolean` method for those 3 parameters. I have written it like this:

```
public double onboardSales;
public double onboardServices;
public double preorderSales;

public void methodName() {

if(taxArea.isEmpty()) {

//onboardSales is tax free;
//onboardServices is tax free;
//preorderSales is tax free;

    }

}

public boolean applyTax(boolean b){
return b;
}
```

Comment: You cant do this in Java

Comment: logically, wouldn´t the value `1` be something like tax free, if you are doing a multiplication at any point in your code?

Comment: I am not going to do any multiplication or any operations. I just want to assign them as tax free or not.

Comment: why does the applyTax() return an boolean?

Comment: @punit1337 then why are they `double`'s in the first place and not `boolean`'s?

Comment: I tried to use applyTax in my if. For example, if() { applyTax(false);      }

Comment: what is applyTax supposed to do?

Comment: My mistake. If I declare them as boolean, how can I write it pragmatically in my if statement?

Comment: What do you mean "pragmatically"? If you mean "To write it as short-hand", the answer if "You should not", because that tends to mess up the readability of the code. But a simple way — if you defind them as `boolean` instead of `double` — would be: `onboardSales = onboardServices = preorderSales = taxArea.isEmpty();`

Comment: I just want to know how to write  " If tax area is empty then, *on board sales, on board services, pre-orders are tax free. " programmatically.

Comment: Sorry about that, my auto-correct is being silly. I meant to say I want to the following statement in Java code.

Comment: @punit1337 I find your question really strange. This is the most basic of operations. Are you honestly asking us how to write `onboardSales = true;`?

Comment: uhm - just don't add the tax if its empty? btw - try to write your logic in pseudo code first - this can help

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors That I already know. I have another boolean called taxFree and I want to know how to assign onboardSales, onboardServies,preorder as taxFree(true or false).

Comment: @punit1337 What, what?! You want to know how to write `onboardSales = taxFree;`? Well there you go.

Comment: ok now I am confused about what you even want to do. So you want the information for each - onboardSales, onboardServices and preorder each if they are taxfree? create an object that contains the information if you need more information than the boolean for each

Answer (score 0):

Java is a statically typed language, which means that the type of each field, and parameter is known at compile time, so you can't put a `boolean` in a `double`.

What you can do is declare an `Object`, to which you can assign a `Boolean` or a `Double`.

Either way, I discourage doing this - at least there is a design smell in your code if you need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In Java the datatype of your variable is either double or boolean. That leaves you with two options: You can either declare an additional variable like that:

```
public boolean taxFree;
public double onboardSales;
public double onboardServices;
public double preorderSales;
```

Or you can use a valid double value (e.g. -1) to indicate "tax freeness". This requires, that the chosen value is not valid in your context.

Comment: Would this work?

if (taxArea.isEmpty()) {          
            onboardSalePct = onboardServicePct = preorderSalePct = applyTax(false);
        }

Answer (score 0):

You must create a variable for the tax, too. The example shows only the onboard sales.

```
// total value of onboard sales
public double onboardSales;
// percentage stored as double. E.g. 0.75 =  75%
public double onboardSalesTax;

public boolean applyTax(String tax){
   if (( tax == null ) || (tax.trim().equals(""))
      onboardSalesTax = 0;
   else
      // maybe you need a better parser here, that computes integers to double 
      // e.g. 75 to 0.75
      onboardSalesTax = Double.parseDouble(tax);
}

// computes the absolute value of the tax 
public boolean computeOnBoardSalesTaxAmount()
{
   return onboardSales * onboardSalesTax;
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to compute anything in my code. I changed my onboardSales,etc to boolean and set them as tax free.